# How Application Insights Intercepts SQL Calls?

Tags: .net, interceptor, azure-application-insights, profiler, jit

Application Insights provides a lot of dependency tracing automatically -- in particular, `DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule` is in charge of it. Among other dependency telemetry it collects all database calls which were doing using `ADO.NET` (basically, all which can be done via `System.Data.SqlClient.`).

I got curious to see how it's implemented inside and opened up IlSpy to review the internals; it was not a big surprise to see code like the below from `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.Implementation.ProfilerRuntimeInstrumentation` class:

```
internal static void DecorateProfilerForSqlCommand(ref ProfilerSqlCommandProcessing sqlCallbacks)
{
    Functions.Decorate("System.Data", "System.Data.dll", "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery", sqlCallbacks.OnBeginForOneParameter, sqlCallbacks.OnEndForOneParameter, sqlCallbacks.OnExceptionForOneParameter, false, true);
    Functions.Decorate("System.Data", "System.Data.dll", "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader", sqlCallbacks.OnBeginForOneParameter, sqlCallbacks.OnEndForOneParameter, sqlCallbacks.OnExceptionForOneParameter, false, true);
    Functions.Decorate("System.Data", "System.Data.dll", "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader", sqlCallbacks.OnBeginForThreeParameters, sqlCallbacks.OnEndForThreeParameters, sqlCallbacks.OnExceptionForThreeParameters, false, true);
    // and others...
}
```

However, the deeper I dig the less I understand how it works. If we look into the `Functions.Decorate` implementation, we will find that it basically delegates the work to 
the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.Decorator.Decorate` method which internally calls `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.Internal.DecoratorInternal`. It then calls `Microsoft.Diagnostics.Instrumentation.Extensions.Intercept.Internal.NativeMethods.Decorate`.

Here is punch line. Below is the implementation of the last method that supposed (to my eye) to do the real work.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
internal static int Decorate(int methodId, long assemblyNamePtr, long moduleNamePtr, long typeNamePtr, long methodNamePtr, uint argsCount)
{
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is -- does anyone know how this is really working?

Comment: Option 1: In runtime one of the methods in this chain is replaced by the actual implementation that inserts OnBegin / OnException and OnEnd appropriately into corresponding blocks within the method (like try/catch/finally). Option 2: This code is not used when method is not replaced in runtime (IsEnabled would return false) and [DiagnosticSource subscription](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/develop/Src/DependencyCollector/Shared/Implementation/SqlClientDiagnosticSourceListener.cs) is used instead.